# How do I calculate the angle at which mouse pointer is present to a certain point?

Tags: javascript

How do I calculate the angle at which the mouse pointer is present relative to the screen right bottom corner?

Comment: "Is it possible?" isn't a good question on SO. You need to make an effort and show your code, then ask something _specific_. We're not a free coding service. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an event listener for `mousemove`, get the coordinates of the mouse with `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`, and use `Math.atan2` to calculate the angle:

```js
var angle = document.getElementById("angle");
var p2 = {
  x: window.innerWidth,
  y: window.innerHeight
};
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  var p1 = {
    x: e.pageX,
    y: e.pageY
  };
  var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
  angle.innerHTML = Math.round(angleDeg);
})
```

```html
Angle: <span id="angle">[move mouse first!]</span>
```

We can take it one step further by playing around with HTML5 Canvas using [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.arc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc) and [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.lineTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "15px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Move your cursor over the canvas to get started", 10, 30);
var p2 = {
  x: window.innerWidth,
  y: window.innerHeight
};
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var p1 = {
    x: e.pageX,
    y: e.pageY
  };
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  var angleDeg = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
  var a = p1.x - p2.x;
  var b = p1.y - p2.y;
  var c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.arc(canvas.width, canvas.height, 50, 1 * Math.PI, 1 * Math.PI + (2 / 360 * Math.round(angleDeg) * Math.PI), false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillText(Math.round(angleDeg)+"°", canvas.width - 70, canvas.height - 20);
})
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: You might want to use `Math.tan(x/y)` instead, but only if you're sure that both values are positive.